# Worlds Tallest Console

Tags: backwards-compatibility

I remember seeing a picture several years ago of "The World's Tallest Console".  It consisted of the first generation Sega Genesis and Sega CD, the 32X, the Game Genie,Sonic and Knuckles, with Sonic 3 plugged into it.

I was checking to see if anyone has that picture or the ability to recreate it?

Bonus points if you can think of a taller one.

Thanks.

Comment: It's important to add stipulations to this.  I'd suggest that it should still be playable and that it should not contain any duplicates.  I know the picture you are talking about, but don't believe I have it.

Comment: You'll be happy to know that this question is the #1 Google general (not image) result for the phrase, world's tallest console sega genesis.

Comment: Yep, I just searched on Google Images and found them, similar results as the non-image search.

Comment: Sorry, but although this stuff is fun, I feel that it is really more like gamer trivia and should be closed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and sorry for not checking google first.  I just thought it would spur some interesting discussion.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this type of question is no more answerable than Game Identification questions that lack artifacts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mean this?

[image]

Source:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/98262177@N00/46286043/

Or, there's another here: http://www.whipassgaming.com/images/weekend/carttowerkeyboardg.jpg

Comment: What the heck *is* all that? :-)

Comment: The 32X add-on allowed you to play 32-bit games, instead of the standard 16-bit Genesis titles.  I bought this in order to play Doom.  The Sonic-n-Nuckles add-on allowed you to insert other Sonic titles, and play those titles as Knuckles instead of Sonic.